# fscanf - how to process two floats + whitespace + newline?

Tags: c, stdio, scanf

Using fscanf I want to process text that contains two floats, an arbitrary amount of whitespace before, between, or after the floats (including newlines/returns), and a newline character at the very end. If there are more/fewer than two numbers, then I want to detect that and report an error.

This seems to work for handling the whitespace, but it won't detect if there's more than two floats present:

```
fscanf(f, "%f %f", &sx, &sy);
```

And this seems to work just as well:

```
fscanf(f, "%f %f%*[ \n\t\r\f\v]\n", &sx, &sy);
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How can your last example catch the last newline? Isn't it get by the regex?

Comment: @effeffe: Good point, I wanted to ensure that there was actually a newline char at the end, otherwise there's no guarantee that the regex finds a newline at all, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Well, that scanf will always fail, no strings could match `%[a]a` format

Comment: @David: What do you exactly mean by whitespace now? Does newline count as a whitespace for you or not?

Comment: @askmish: in Standard C newline is white-space, and he put newline in his regex and in his question, so... yes. From the OP: _"... (including newlines/returns), and a newline character at the very end."_

Comment: And that's a totally vague question. Because we do not have any idea where is the end of OP's input line?

Comment: @askmish: yes, we don't know what's beyond this "regex", so we should simply check for the sequence `whitespace-float-whitespace-float-whitespaceEndingWithNewline`, and this is what I'm trying to achieve with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with a single *scanf, I don't think it's possible due to the last part of your request, *scanf can't read an arbitrary length character sequence matching a simple regex **and ending with a specified character**.

```
int character;
bool trailingNewLine;

if (fscanf(f, "%f%f", &sx, &sy) < 2)
    // not matching "whitespace-float-whitespace-float"
    // being more accurate could be painful...

// read arbitrary quantity of white space ending with '\n'
while (isspace(character = getc(f)))
    trailingNewLine = (character == '\n');

// the last one wasn't white space, doesn't belong to this one
ungetc(character, f);

if (!trailingNewLine)
    // missing newline at the end

// OK!
```

Comment: Your solution will work, only if the arbitrary whitespaces in between do not include a newline. :) The `isspace()` does check newline too.

Comment: Are you talking about white space between the two floats? C11 Standard states that this is the first step of a conversion specification: _"Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.)"_ so newlines in between should be read and discarded before reading the second float... am I misunderstanding this or your comment?

Comment: I am talking about the whitespaces in-between the 2nd float and the end-of-line newline character. `1.2 2.3 \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n(I am talking about this space)\n\n`

Comment: It's also an error if the `fscanf()` call returns 1. Anything but 2, in fact, is an error, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
fscanf(f, "%f%f", &one, &two);
while (1) {
  ch = fgetc(f);
  if (ch == EOF) /* end of input whithout a line break */break;
  if (ch == '\n') /* input ok */break;
  if (!isspace((unsigned char)ch)) /* bad input */break;
}
```

Comment: :did you mean to using fscanf or scanf?

Comment: This seems to work, I was hoping there was a way just using fscanf but perhaps not.

Comment: How can this handle multiple trailing newlines at the end? And I don't think that cast is necessary

Comment: @askmish: my bad: I just copied and pasted the original code and didn't pay attention. It's `fscanf()` and I'm missing a stream in the arguments.

Comment: @effeffe: the cast is required under penalty of undefined behaviour. Look at 7.4/1 in the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) or [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: And `getchar` wouldn't work, while reading from file. I think you meant `fgetc`?

Comment: Thanks @askmish, post ammended again :)

Comment: @pmg: _"In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF."_ sorry but I don't understand. ch is returned from fgetc, which can olny return EOF (and you check it) or a valid character. The cast would be useful if you don't know what the int contains, but there ch must contain a valid character, right?

Comment: But, `isspace()` also does check for newlines too!

Comment: Well ... you're right in this instance @effeffe. I just associate the functions in `<ctype.h>` with a need to cast and don't even look where the data comes from. The point here is that `fgetc()` returns the character as an **unsigned char**. Passing a negative value to the functions in `<ctype.h>` is UB.

Comment: @askmish: my `isspace()` check is after the check for newlines. The snippet above is just that: a *snippet*. In a real program you would set some flag or something before the break.

Comment: ... but this snippet still doesn't handle multiple newlines at the end

Answer (score 1):

If you are specific about how many characters you have to read in(or have any idea max. no. of characters in a line) use:
`fread ( stringbuffer, size, count,Filepointer );`

Then use:
`sscanf()` to read in the two float, then use a `for` loop to count the no. of white spaces in the read string.

You can also use `strtok()`.

NOTE: Reading a input stream until end-of-line(where end-of-line is marked by a new line in your case) including whitespaces in between(because in C, atleast, whitespace does include new lines, too) is too vague. Better read data in chunks in that case using `fread` and process the stored data till you reach your specific end-of-line.

Comment: If you want to use isspace(), check if its newline too and if its the end-of-line as per your specifications too.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%f %f%*c", &sx, &sy);
// %*c will read and discard all eventual characters after the second float
```